# When a tab is revisited a new set of views are generated leading to a potential stack overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have an application based on Josh Smith's MVVM Demo, with the business logic replaced. The user clicks links that dynamically generate tabs. Each tab has a view and viewmodel. The tab views contain child views one of which contains multiple OxyPlot PlotViews. The user is presented with multiple plots, and zooming on one plot will cause all the plots to zoom accordingly. This has worked well on my applications with hard-coded tabs.

The problem occurs when the user goes back to a previously selected tab. All the views in the hierarchy are recreated, but the old views are not deleted.

I have added static counters to my views, so I can keep track of what is happening with otherwise identical views. If the user zooms a plot on a revisited tab, I can see all the views and the copies getting zoomed. The more times a user switches tabs, the more copies that are created.

I actually had a stack overflow because the Oxyplot zoom was causing recursion and an infinite loop. I replaced the zoom with individual min/max settings, which solved that problem, but I still need to get rid of the extra view copies.

Here is the view that contains the PlotView:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DataPlot.Views.GenericTrackView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataPlot.Views"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Loaded="GenericTrackView_OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="OuterGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="460*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Click="Button_Click">
                        <TextBlock Text="-" Margin="0,-8,0,0" FontSize="28"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Menu Height="30">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding TrackName}">
                            <MenuItem Header="IsLogarithmic" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsLogarithmic}"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>

                </StackPanel>

                <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Filters" Header="Filters" Visibility="{Binding FiltersVisible}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="FrequencyItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Frequencies}"
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding FrequenciesEnabled}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding FrequenciesVisible}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName }"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                        <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=FrequencyItems, Path=DataContext.SelectFrequencyCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=FrequencyItems, Path=DataContext.ToggleFrequencyCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                        </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ComponentItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Components}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding ComponentsEnabled}"
                              Visibility="{Binding ComponentsVisible}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding ComponentName }"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                        <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=ComponentItems, Path=DataContext.SelectComponentCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=ComponentItems, Path=DataContext.ToggleComponentCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                        </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="SpacingsItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Spacings}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding SpacingsEnabled}"
                              Visibility="{Binding SpacingsVisible}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding SpacingName }"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                        <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=SpacingsItems, Path=DataContext.SelectSpacingCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=SpacingsItems, Path=DataContext.ToggleSpacingCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                        </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>

                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="CheckBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Curves}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                    <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick"
                                                      Command="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxItems, Path=DataContext.SelectOnlyCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                    </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>

            </Grid>

            <GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitter" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Gray" ShowsPreview="True" Width="3" DragCompleted="GridSplitter_DragCompleted"/>

            <oxy:PlotView x:Name="Plot" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" Grid.Column="2" Loaded="Plot_OnLoaded" MinHeight="{Binding MinimumPlotHeight}">
                <oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <oxy:TrackerControl Position="{Binding Position}" LineExtents="{Binding PlotModel.PlotArea}">
                            <oxy:TrackerControl.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f0e0e0ff" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#f0ffffff" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </oxy:TrackerControl.Background>
                            <oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="7" />
                            </oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                        </oxy:TrackerControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
            </oxy:PlotView>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind

```cs
public partial class GenericTrackView : UserControl, ITrackView
{
    #region Fields

    private TrackContainerView _parentView;
    private static int Count;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public GenericTrackView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Count++;

        // for debugging, keep track of redundant views
        ID = Count;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Track", typeof(Track), typeof(GenericTrackView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnTrackChanged));

    public Track Track
    {
        get => (Track)GetValue(TrackProperty);
        set => SetValue(TrackProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(GenericTrackView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public Axis XAxis { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInternalChange { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private static void OnTrackChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var trackPanel = sender as GenericTrackView;
        if (trackPanel == null)
            return;

        var track = (Track)e.NewValue;
    }

    private void OnAxisChanged(object sender, AxisChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if true then stop any recursion
        if (IsInternalChange)
            return;

        var xMin = XAxis.ActualMinimum;
        var xMax = XAxis.ActualMaximum;

        foreach (var track in _parentView.TrackList)
        {
            if (track == this)
                continue;

            var genericTrack = track as GenericTrackView;

            genericTrack.IsInternalChange = true;

            // do not use zoom to set axis, it can lead to recursion
            genericTrack.XAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = xMin;
            genericTrack.XAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = xMax;
            genericTrack.Plot.InvalidatePlot(false);
            genericTrack.IsInternalChange = false;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}: {ID}";
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button == null)
            return;

        IsActive = !IsActive;
        Plot.Visibility = IsActive ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        CheckBoxItems.Visibility = IsActive ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        GridSplitter.Visibility = IsActive ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        Filters.Visibility = IsActive ? ((GenericTrackViewModel)DataContext).FiltersVisible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (button.Content is TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            textBlock.Text = IsActive ? "-" : "+";
        }
        else
        {
            button.Content = IsActive ? "-" : "+";
        }

        // We need to toggle the Grid.RowDefinition.Height from "*" to "Auto" in order
        // for the row to collapse.
        // We know this control is in a ContentPresenter, which is a child of the Grid.
        // The Grid is the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl. So first we find the Grid,
        // then we find and set the row that this TrackPanelView is in.
        var grid = WpfHelpers.FindParentControl<Grid>(this);
        if (grid == null)
            return;

        var index = 0;
        foreach (var contentPresenter in grid.Children)
        {
            var dependencyObject = contentPresenter as DependencyObject;
            if (dependencyObject == null)
                continue;

            var panel = WpfHelpers.FindFirstVisualChild<GenericTrackView>(dependencyObject);
            if (Equals(panel, this))
            {
                grid.RowDefinitions[index].Height = IsActive ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) : new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void GridSplitter_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gridSplitter = sender as GridSplitter;
        if (gridSplitter == null)
            return;

        if (!(Math.Abs(e.HorizontalChange) > 0.0))
            return;

        foreach (var trackView in _parentView.TrackList)
        {
            if (!Equals(trackView, this))
            {
                ((GenericTrackView)trackView).OuterGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = OuterGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the plot is loaded, find the x axis and link its AxisChanged event to the
    /// OnAxisChanged method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Plot_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var axis in Plot.ActualModel.Axes)
        {
            if (axis.Position != AxisPosition.Bottom)
                continue;

            XAxis = axis;
            break;
        }

        if (XAxis != null)
            XAxis.AxisChanged += OnAxisChanged;
    }

    private void GenericTrackView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Name = ((GenericTrackViewModel)DataContext).TrackName;

        // find parent and add this track to its list
        _parentView = WpfHelpers.FindParentControl<TrackContainerView>(this);
        _parentView.TrackList.Add(this);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

In my viewmodels, I am not using PlotModel, I am using ViewResolvingPlotModel as described in a previous post:

[OxyPlot - This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78063953/oxyplot-this-plotmodel-is-already-in-use-by-some-other-plotview-control)

I don't know if the code I have shown is helpful, as I don't understand what the root cause of the problem is. All the connections between views and viewmodels are done through DataTemplates. I see no code in my MainWindowViewModel that is called when a user switches tabs.

The viewmodel is created as follows.

```cs
private void ShowPipelineTest()
{
    var workspace = new TestPipelineViewModel();
    Workspaces.Add(workspace);
    SetActiveWorkspace(workspace);
}

void SetActiveWorkspace(WorkspaceViewModel workspace)
{
    Debug.Assert(Workspaces.Contains(workspace));

    var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Workspaces);
    collectionView?.MoveCurrentTo(workspace);
}
```

But this code is not called when the tab is revisited.

Edit: I found some code for testing. The original MVVM Demo can be found here:

https://github.com/djangojazz/JoshSmith_MVVMDemo

I had problems with the solution, but the project opened and worked. First open an All Customers tab, then a New Customer tab. When you click back on the first tab you will see the view get instantiated again. That is the problem. My application uses the same MainWindowView and the same MainWondowViewModel with my tab viewmodels replacing those in the demo.

Comment: You have navigation issues but don't show any related code...!? I suggest removing all the code that is not required to reproduce the issue or simplify it and add the code that is absolutely required. Right now, this is just a weird question because the posted code seems to be totally out of context. We need something to review, if that makes sense.

Comment: That is a good point. Right now, I see no code related to the navigation issue. When I look at the stack trace just before an extraneous view is instantiated, I see [External Code].

Comment: You should not wrap the ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer. You don't want to scroll the ItemsControl. You want to scroll its items. To accomplish this, you would have to override the ControlTemplate and wrap the ItemsPresenter into the ScrollViewer instead. The ListBox already does this for you and also provides some great performance features you don't want to miss. I recommend using the ListBox instead of the plain ItemsControl (which is the base class of ListBox). You can remove the highlight effects by overriding the ControlTemplate of the ListBoxItem (which only contains a ContentPresenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some private discussion with BionicCode, in order to make it more claer what I was trying to do with my code. He quickly found the problem was my handlers were keeping the garbage collector from cleaning up the extra objects. I had to add some Unloaded handlers. Here is the latest code, which has been moved to a base class, so it is a little different.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// When the plot is loaded, find the x axis and link its AxisChanged event to the
    /// OnAxisChanged method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Plot_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Plot = sender as PlotView;
        foreach (var axis in Plot.ActualModel.Axes)
        {
            if (axis.Position != AxisPosition.Bottom)
                continue;
        
            XAxis = axis;
            break;
        }
        
        if (XAxis != null)
            XAxis.AxisChanged += OnAxisChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the plot is unloaded, unlink its AxisChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Plot_UnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (XAxis != null)
            XAxis.AxisChanged -= OnAxisChanged;
    }

    protected void TrackView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Name = ((ITrackViewModel)DataContext).TrackName;

        // find parent and add this track to its list
        _parentView = WpfHelpers.FindParentControl<TrackContainerView>(this);
        _parentView.TrackList.Add(this);
    }

    protected void TrackView_UnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // remove this from parent.
        if (_parentView != null && _parentView.TrackList.Contains(this))
            _parentView.TrackList.Remove(this);
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `TabControl` works: it's a list of `TabItem` headers where each show their content in the *single shared content host* of the `TabControl`.
Of course, this means that switching between tabs results in recreating the content elements because the `DataTemplate` is reapplied. The only exception is when the `DataTemplate` is reused because the data type of the content remains the same (in this case only the data binding targets are updated).

You can avoid recreation of particular template controls by declaring them as a resource. `UIElement` elements are shared by default (and can't be rendered multiple times simultaneously i.e. can't exist in the visual tree multiple times *at the same time*).

Please note that the discarded `DataTemplate` elements are normally garbage collected (unless you explicitly prevent them from becoming eligible (e.g. by storing the instance reference in an instance variable of a type that has a longer lifetime or in a class (static) variable. In this case you would have to explicitly remove the reference by setting the variable to `null`).
Whether you wrongfully *believe* that those elements are never collected or they eventually stay in memory is not possible to tell based on your posted code. But because of the `DataTemplate` context I'm pretty sure that they are properly garbage collected in the end. Garbage collection doesn't occur instantly.

**App.xaml**
Declare a globally shared instance of `GenericTrackView`:

```xml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <GenericTrackView x:Key="SharedGenericTrackView" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Reference the resource in the `DataTemplate` using a content host:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate>

      <!-- 
           Now any time this DataTemplate is re-/created, 
           the same instance of GenericTrackView is rendered 
      -->
      <ContentControl Conten="{StaticResource SharedGenericTrackView}" />
    <DataTemplate>
  <Window.Resources>

<Window>
```

Comment: Your code is very interesting and informative. I tried it and indeed got only one plot. Unfortunately, I am trying to create multiple plots, in this case 3 plots, on each tab. I have an observation on how tabs work. I have a similar application where all the tabs are hard-coded in the main XAML. Each tab has a separate view. As I switch tabs, the views are not recreated. That is the behavior I want.

Comment: I have added a static counter to the GenericTrackView containing the plot. I created 3 named plots on a tab and a tab with no plots. After switching tabs 7 times, and zooming on one plot, I could see my OnAxisChanged method run 7 times over 3 plots each time. I could possibly have multiple tabs with 30+ plots each. If the user is switching tabs and zooming the response could be sluggish.

Comment: You have not shown your code so I have provided a general example how to reuse the same instance of a control inside a DataTemplate. You can apply the pattern to a smaller scope. For example, add a control for each tab to the resources. For this you would have to create a dedicated type for each tab content. You would create a common interface or abstract class that each tab content item implements/realizes. This way you can define a dedicated DataTemplate for each type where each DataTemplate references its own user control from the resource dictionary.

Comment: If the tabs are hard-coded, then simply add an instance of the user control to each `TabItem.Resources` property. This way each tab will have it own instance

Comment: Regarding your zooming issue: it's not clear how you zoom the plot. Unless all the plot controls use the same data elements then each plot control should zoom independently.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense because there is only one tab content loaded. This means there must be some shared data or plot view state between all the plot views that causes that modifying one plot view (does it modify the data?) affects all others.

Comment: The tabs are not hard-coded in my application. The tabs are created exactly as in the MVVM Demo that I linked in my question. I only mentioned hard-coded tabs to note that I have a similar application with hard-coded tabs that does not have the same problem. I do not want hard-coded tabs because that would limit the number of workspaces I can have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257059/discussion-between-spainchaud-and-bioniccode).